# onmouseover/out inside input text box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a text to show and hide inside an input box I made.
I know that it's supposed to be like this:

```
onmouseover=this.style.display="block";
onmouseout=this.style.display="none";
```

I just don't know where to put it. Should I put it in the `<input>`?
Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS.css"/>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload= "load();">
    <span id="imvite">Invite:</span>
    <input /><br></br>

    <span id="time">Time:</span>
    <input /><br></br>

    <span id="place">Place:</span>
    <input /><br></br>
</body>
</html>
```

When I wrote it after the `<input>` the text was showing all the time, and it was not even in the textbox.
Like this:

```
<span id="imvite">Invite:</span>
<input /><br></br>

<span id="time">Time:</span>
<input /><br></br>

<span id="place">Place:</span>
<input onmouseover=this.style.display="block"; my text here />
```

How can I make a text to appear and disappear inside my textbox with those functions?

I hope I'm clear, thanks for the help.

Comment: Wait! How can you hover an element, if it has `display: none` set?

Comment: Do you meaning show input value? because is not possible insert content in `input` element

Comment: `<input onmouseover="this.style.display='block';">`

Comment: to show text in an input field, you need to address the `value` of the input field.

Comment: `<input type="text" value="My text here" onmouseover="this.style.display='block'">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input
    onmouseover="this.value=this.getAttribute('data-value');" 
    data-value="text" 
    onmouseout="this.value='';" 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/8nL9gr1h/

HTML:

```
<input onmouseover="this.value='my text here';" onmouseout="this.value='';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
    onmouseover="this.value=this.getAttribute('data-value');" 
    data-value="text" 
    onmouseout="this.value='';" 
/>
```

Works, sort of, the problem is that when you mouse out, anything you typed is blanked and when you mouse over again, it just displays text. Another answer (which may not work if you want everything to be contained in the one HTML Document is to add a Class to you inputs and give it a :hover in a CSS file and link that file in the Head of your HTML, putting any changes to the styling in your CSS.